# chrome.tabs.query status:loading -> exception?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an exception for the `chrome.tabs.query` status of my browser extension.

My code currently looks like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    "active":        true,
    "currentWindow": true,
    "status":        "loading",   // <-- this line
    "windowType":    "normal"
}, ...);
```

But for *www.gmx.net* and *www.web.de* the status should be `"complete"`. Can anyone tell me how am I able to create this exception?

Comment: Why the firefox-addon tag?

Comment: because the extension is available for chrome and firefox :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **add the `url: []` property to the query information**, like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    "active":        true,
    "currentWindow": true,
    "status":        "complete",
    "windowType":    "normal",
    "url": ["*://www.gmx.net/*", "*://www.web.de/*"]
}, ...);
```

The above code will check for tabs that have completed loading, but only the ones that are either on *gmx.net* or *web.de*.

**You can then combine the two queries and use the same function**, like this:

```
function myFunction(tabs) {
    if (~tab.url.indexOf('www.gmx.net') || ~tab.url.indexOf('www.web.de')) {
        // the tab is on gmx.net or web.de and is complete
    } else {
        // the tab is not on gmx.net nor web.de and is still loading
    }
};

chrome.tabs.query({
    "active":        true,
    "currentWindow": true,
    "status":        "loading",
    "windowType":    "normal"
}, myFunction);

chrome.tabs.query({
    "active":        true,
    "currentWindow": true,
    "status":        "complete",
    "windowType":    "normal",
    "url": ["*://www.gmx.net/*", "*://www.web.de/*"]
}, myFunction);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your question, then consider marking it as correct to let other people with the same problem find it easily!